# How to download Unity dots (entity package) with unity 2020.3 LTS?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I decided to try out the new unity dots system, or, the new entities package (as well as the hybrid renderer), but I can't find the package in the package manager with preview packages enabled. After looking it up, I could not find any resources, other than one that told me that they moved some of the preview packages ***out*** of the package manager, and somewhere else. Does anyone have any idea where it could be?

This is what it looks like on my screen by the way:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Entity Component System - DOTS Project Setup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.17/manual/install_setup.html)

> Starting with Unity **2020.1**, the DOTS packages are **not listed in the package manager, even when preview packages are enabled.** There are two alternative options to install those packages:
>
> - You can use `"Add package from git URL..."` under the + menu at the top left of the package manager to add packages either by name (such as `com.unity.entities`), or by git URL (but this option isn't available for DOTS packages). Note that it might take a few moments before the package starts installing.
> - Alternatively, you can add DOTS packages by directly editing the `Packages\manifest.json` file in your project. This file requires not only the package name but also a version which can be found by looking at the documentation of each package (such as `"com.unity.entities" : "x.x.x-preview.x"`).

For example currently it would be `com.unity.entities" : "0.17.0-preview.41"`

And

> Follow the link for more information about [installing hidden packages](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/Installation/manual/index.html).

Maybe also interesting for you:

> The recommended set of core packages to be added to a DOTS project is:
>
> - com.unity.entities
> - com.unity.rendering.hybrid
> - com.unity.dots.editor

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thank you! That worked!